# CFAlert Custom Plugin button function

Tags: objective-c, swift

any one help me out with add the button function on the 'UPGRADE NOW' Button

```
func showPopup(){

        // Create Alet View Controller
        let alertController = CFAlertViewController(title: "Your Trial Plan Expires Soon",
                                                    message: "Thank you for using our services. Your Trial plan ends on Date",
                                                    textAlignment: .center,
                                                    preferredStyle: .actionSheet,
                                                    didDismissAlertHandler: nil)

        // Create Upgrade Action
        let defaultAction = CFAlertAction(title: "UPGRADE NOW",
                                          style: .Default,
                                          alignment: .center,
                                          backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.8235, green: 0, blue: 0.9882, alpha: 1.0),
                                          textColor: nil,
                                          handler: { (action) in
                                            print("Button with title '" + action.title! + "' tapped")
        })


        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

The Button a URL to the broswer

```
objc func clickOnConpany() {

        /*let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterationViewController") as! RegisterationViewController
        vc.isRegisterForCompany = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)*/

        self.showAlert(with: "Alert!", andMessage: "In order to register as company visit website.", andSecondary: "Ok") {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let sfSafriVC = SFSafariViewController.init(url: API.getOpenableLink(with: API.AppUrl.emploerLogin))
                self.present(sfSafriVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        }

    }
```

Please any one help me to add button function to the 'UPGRADE NOW' button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `defaultAction` put the code you want  in the `handler`:

```swift
        let defaultAction = CFAlertAction(
            title: "UPGRADE NOW",
            style: .Default,
            alignment: .center,
            backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.8235, green: 0, blue: 0.9882, alpha: 1.0),
            textColor: nil,
            handler: { _ in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let sfSafriVC = SFSafariViewController.init(url: API.getOpenableLink(with: API.AppUrl.emploerLogin))
                    self.present(sfSafriVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        )
```